# What is the representation of a tree in a heap called?

Tags: data-structures

Often a binary tree is represented in a particular [implicit data structure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_data_structure) packed into an array whereby the left and right children of `t[x]` are found at `t[2x+1]` and `t[2x+2]`. This is commonly done in implementations of heaps, for example.

Does this representation have a canonical name? I am somewhat fed up of referring to it as “a representation of a tree in an array like in a heap”.

Comment: I don't think there's an official name (hence this being a comment rather than an answer - I have no proof), but I tend to use "array-embedded [binary] tree", it's at least shorter and easier to work into a sentence.

Comment: You’d think it would have one huh. Maybe we should coin one...

Comment: In any particular document, you can say once that you always implement trees in this way and then just say "tree".

Comment: Indeed, "array implementation of [complete] binary trees" seems to be acceptable, as witnessed by a google search. If you want to have fun, just call it an "[Ahnentafel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahnentafel)", or "[Eytzinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micha%C3%ABl_Eytzinger)'s method", after the person who described this method for numbering in (geneological) trees around 1590.

Comment: "In effect, an ahnentafel is a method for storing a binary tree in an array" - the one used in heaps. Perfect! An Ahnentafel it is then :-)